# joomla 3.6 Создание полей ввода в админпанели

Tags: php, joomla, шаблоны, joomla3

Я только осваиваю Joomla!

Немного знаком с Drupal, там можно было написать модуль так, чтобы можно было редактировать каждый параграф, заголовок и тд.

Я создал модуль, создал позицию, отобразил модуль.

Но в редакторе, если выключить отображение html, получается неразбериха. "весь текст наляпан, да еще и "абзацы" хаотичные" - так будет смотреть заказчик, только он уберет один "абзац", так верстка и посыпалась

Прошу указать, в какую сторону смотреть и где почитать, да хотя бы как правильно это в джумле называется.

Хотелось бы по переходу в модуль увидеть поля: заголовок блока, содержание блока, картинка блока, почта, телефон, адрес, кнопка "связаться"(редактировать текст кнопки)
Не создавать же для каждого пункта отдельный модуль...
Единственное, что есть в стандартном редакторе, это заголовок и содержание, можно еще картинку прилепить

Comment: "Я только осваиваю Joomla... будет смотреть заказчик, только он уберет один "абзац", так верстка и посыпалась" - зачем Вы взяли работу, которую пока не можете выполнить качественно?

Comment: @Streletz это было обговоренно заранее и будет сделано бесплатно. Я front-end занимают, но решил освоить джумлу. На реальном проекте мне проще учить. Сайт по сути не сложны(3 страницы, главная - лендинг, сделал за 1 день, по сути не сложный, как раз, чтобы учить новое).Так что заказчик обо всем знает :)

Comment: Это роли не играет. Ведь заказчик наверняка хочет получить результат в полном соответствии с ТЗ, верно? Иначе зачем Вы задали этот вопрос на ruSO? Добрый совет - учиться, во всяком случае осваивать "базу", лучше на учебных проектах. Создайте тестовый сайт и на нём отрабатывайте базовые приёмы работы. Поверьте, это гораздо эффективнее, чем искать проект "за бесплатно" и для нервной системы спокойнее. Реальный проект = реальная ответственность (всегда!)!

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил. Может кому в будущем надо будет.

1. Создается категория. Например "CustomCategory"
2. Далее создаются материалы, в которых укзаываем "Родительский элемент" - CustomCategory
3. Создается пункт меню. В типа указываем "Материал". Далее "Тип пункта меню *
   " - Блок категории и указываем CustomCategory

Так можно вывести сколько угодно материалов на одной странице. Так можно сделать для удобства блоки.

4. Как я писал выше, помимо заголовка, текста и картинки, в моем случае, надо еще почта, адрес, икоки соц.сетей, телефон. Т.к. эти пункты редактируются крайне редко, то я создал каждому из них модуль и вписал туда нужный код.
5. В нужном материале в редакторе кликаем на "Модуль", добавляем нужный модуль в нужное место и вуаля.

В случае с заказчиком, говорим, что это трогать нельзя и все, а там уже пусть ставит пробелы, абзацы и тд